# PaperJS, Need to select items underneath a transparent raster using Mouse Down

Tags: paperjs

I have a Canvas with multiple raster images.
I use `onMouseDown` on `Tool` to find select the item which was clicked.

I have a new requirement.

Suppose, two images overlap each other, and the upper image is partially transparent. That makes the lower image visible. But when I try to click on the lower image, obviously I end up choosing the upper image.

**Failed Attempt**

I tried to use the `getPixel(point)` function on Raster. I thought if I can figure that the selected pixel is transparent, I can ignore that raster and look for other items. But I am not getting the color value that I am expecting (transparent or not) using this function.

So, my second thought was that I need to change the mousedown event point from the global co-ordinate space to local raster co-ordinate space. It still did not work.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Code

```
tool.onMouseDown = (event) => {    
      project.activeLayer.children.forEach((item) => {

    if (item.contains(event.point)) {
          // check if hit was on a transparent raster pixel
          const pixel = item.getPixel(event.point)
          console.error(pixel.toCSS(true))

         // 2nd attempt
          const pixel = item.getPixel(item.globalToLocal(event.point))
          console.error(pixel.toCSS(true))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simpler way to do what you want to achieve.
You can rely on [project.hitTestAll()](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#hittestall-point) method to do a hit test on all items.
Then, if the hit item is a raster, hit pixel color information will be contained in [hitResult.color](http://paperjs.org/reference/hitresult/). `hitResult.color.alpha` is all you need to check if a raster was hit on a non-transparent pixel.

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.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) demonstration of the solution.

```
const dataUrl = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
const lowOpacity = 0.3;

// create 2 rasters
new Raster({
    source: dataUrl,
    opacity: lowOpacity,
    onLoad: function() {
        this.position = view.center - 100;
    }
});
new Raster({
    source: dataUrl,
    opacity: lowOpacity,
    onLoad: function() {
        this.position = view.center + 100;
    }
});

// on mouse down
function onMouseDown(event) {
    // unselect previously selected items
    paper.project.selectedItems.forEach(item => {
        item.selected = false;
        item.opacity = lowOpacity;
    });

    // do a hit test on all project items
    const hitResults = project.hitTestAll(event.point);
    // for each hit result
    for (let i = 0; i < hitResults.length; i++) {
        const hitResult = hitResults[i];
        // if item was hit on a non transparent pixel
        if (hitResult && hitResult.color && hitResult.color.alpha > 0) {
            // select item
            hitResult.item.selected = true;
            hitResult.item.opacity = 1;
            // break loop
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @sasensi. Exactly what I needed.